# « Le/la <nom/adjectif> à <nom de personne> » : apport en qualification inusité ?

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, québec, régionalismes, à

Lors d'un [échange](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25253/la-passe-descendant#comment49882_25253) dans une autre question, je me suis rappelé ce tour avec la préposition *à* en sandwich entre la substantivation d'un (article défini avec l') adjectif, par exemple, et un nom (et plus particulièrement un nom de famille, lors du précédent millénaire, employé chez quelqu'un de plutôt érudit, à l'oral, au Québec) :

> Le niaiseux à [nom de famille], il...
>  Le cornichon à [nom de famille]...

Il s'agit d'un **apport en qualification** (c'est : [nom de famille] *le niaiseux*, un peu comme l'[épithète](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4661)) et non de l'appartenance, du moins dans le sens le plus usuel de l'appartenance, malgré la marque de l'apport en complémentation (la préposition). D'où ma difficulté à l'analyser, et à en étayer l'emploi...

---

- S'agit-il de l'appartenance de la caractéristique, pour ainsi dire,
  ou est-ce basé sur un tour plus ancien, sur le style d'un auteur ou d'une époque en particulier, que fait ce tour que l'épithète ne ferait-il pas, est-ce vraiment comme l'épithète sans préposition ou que sais-je d'[autre](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/763/3177) ?
- Comment un article avec un nom ou un adjectif suivi de la préposition *à* et du nom de personne en sont-ils arrivés à réaliser un apport en qualification et comment
  analyse-t-on la fonction de la préposition et celle du nom qui la précède ici ; et a-t-on une comparaison avec un autre emploi similaire avec la
  préposition *à* ?
- Ailleurs qu'au Québec est-ce que l'on aurait reconnu ce tour-là,    comment le perçoit-on, le retrouve-t-on quelque part ?

Comment: Si j'ai bien compris la tournure: *Ailleurs qu'au Québec est-ce que l'on aurait reconnu ce tour-là ?* Probablement pas. *Comment le perçoit-on?* Pas comme signifiant « [nom] le niais » mais comme se référant à quelqu'un de niais dans l'entourage de [nom]. *Le retrouve-t-on quelque part ?* Pas à ma connaissance.

Comment: Jamais lu/entendu cet emploi en France ou en Belgique. Même chose que jiliagre pour le sens perçu ici.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci, _quelqu'un de niais ds. l'entourage de [nom]_ est une interprétation fort intéressante, avec en arrière-plan peut-être l'idée de _bande de_. C'est plus clair pour moi même au figuré que l'_appartenance de la caractéristique_. Votre propos laisserait entendre que peut-être la personne qui a dit ça ne voulait pas qu'on puisse dire qu'elle parlait directement de la personne à qui elle s'adressait. N'hésitez pas à répondre à une partie de la réponse, peut-être avec une brève vérification  préalable pour le _pas à ma connaissance_.

Comment: L'impératif en français ne possède que la 1ère personne du pluriel et les 2e personnes. Pour les 3e, il est inhabituel de donner des ordres à ceux auxquels on ne s'adresse pas, mais pour laisser comprendre qu'une contrainte leur sera imposée, on peut contourner le problème par le futur simple *(il mangera, n'ayez crainte!)*. Pour se parler à soi, il faut utiliser l'une des personnes disponible, les 3 cas forçant une espèce de dédoublement de soi: une partie de soi parle, une autre écoute (ce dédoublement est même admis par Grevisse). (à suivre...→)

Comment: Considérant que le dédoublement virtuel de l'individu est «admis» en français, se pourrait-il qu'il y ait un lien avec la tournure décrite ici? _Le crétin à Machin_ indiquerait la partie de Machin que ce dernier expose le plus souvent, et qui n'est pas le tout de Machin? Je ne crois pas que la tournure soit ainsi comprise aujourd'hui, mais peut-être une idée à inspecter...

Comment: @Feelew Merci, fort intéressant aussi. Il aurait fallu un peu plus de contexte p-ê., la personne parle directement à son interlocuteur qui fait partie d'un groupe, mais utilise 3SG presque systématiquement. L'appartenance, l'entourage, le dédoublement avec la composante saillante, l'adoucissement etc. sont toutes des manières d'articuler ce qui se passe comme transaction pour ainsi dire (Q.1). Ou est-ce une ancienne manière de concevoir la possession que ce que vous expliquez, etc. ? Le tour décrit fait vieillot pour moi ou je ne sais comment définir ; pourquoi ? Merci.

Answer (score 3):

**Ailleurs qu'au Québec est-ce que l'on aurait reconnu ce tour-là ?**

Pas dans un usage standard. Partant de là la réponse sera (trop) simple.
Sauf si l'on prend en compte un usage dialectal ou local non reconnu comme grammaticalement correct, cet usage de "à" ne se trouve pas.

**Ceci dit...**

Le mot "à" est difficile du fait de sa simplicité et de ses multiples origines. Latin "ad", Germain "an", ancêtres de ceux-ci, mot gaulois, etc.

Il exprime notamment une juxtaposition et pas forcément une appartenance (notamment si on prend en compte "ad" au locatif, ou même au directif), par exemple *Le paysan est aux champs.*. Dans beaucoup de cas en français moderne la situation n'est pas clair (le pré aux boeufs, la jeune fille à la perle, la marre aux canards) et l'on tranche en disant que à exprime aussi une attribution.

Prnons cet usage au figuré, et il pourrait ressortir quelque chose de similaire à ce que vous décrivez.

Comment: Merci ! La fonction de complément du nom, et celle rattachée à l'origine, avec la préposition _ab_ en latin par exemple, est-ce que ça expliquerait ou catégoriserait mieux cette juxtaposition que la fonction d'épithète ou généralement l'idée que qualification ; _à_ peut-il valoir _de_ ?

Comment: Oui, peut-être, mais il ne devrait pas ;). Je parle de mémoire ici. La "dérive" de "à" est à mon avis d'abord celle du bas latin en fait (revenu à la mode au moyen âge à l´epoque où le francais s'est allégé de ses influences germaniques). L'explication serait peut-être à chercher vers l'origine de "de" qui est d'abord démonstratif. Quant à "ab" qui est un mot très ancien à rapprocher de toutes les traductions de "papa" je me demande bien pourquoi il a été "mangé" par "de" dans les langues latines (en anglais il y a "of", langues germaniques "ab", etc).